# Laravel Blade @yield @include ordering

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

i'm using laravel 5.2.
i try using @include to load global layout code
and using @yield for page-related code

it seems to me that @yield is loaded before @include, even though i put @include before @yield in master page

and it's somehow become like this:
1. jquery not loaded before page related script
2. html code in @yield loaded before css and js so the result become a mess

here is what my master page looks like

**Master Page**

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en-us">
<head>
    @include('memberIncludes.memberHead') <!--css and jquery is here -->
</head>

<body>
    @include('memberIncludes.memberHeader')
    @include('memberIncludes.memberMenu')

    @yield('content')  <!-- page related html code -->

    @include('memberIncludes.memberFooter')
    @include('memberIncludes.globalScript')

    @yield('footerScript') <!-- page related script -->
</body>
```

And here is my child page structure

**Child Page**

```
@extends('masterPage')

@section('content')
    <div id="main" role="main">
       ...
    </div>
@end

@section('footerScript')
    <!-- PAGE RELATED PLUGIN(S) -->    
    <!-- Flot Chart Plugin: Flot Engine, Flot Resizer, Flot Tooltip -->
    <script src="js/plugin/flot/jquery.flot.cust.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/plugin/flot/jquery.flot.resize.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/plugin/flot/jquery.flot.time.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/plugin/flot/jquery.flot.tooltip.min.js"></script>
    ...

    <script>
       $(document).ready(function() {
          ...
       });
   </script>
@end
```

is there any way so @yield is loaded as ordered in master page?

Comment: Can you share the actual html output generated by the child page after execution? And the contents of the `include` files..

Comment: @HuzaibShafi thanks man

Answer (score 2):

Well this is embarassing, it's a syntax error

@section should end with @stop. not @end

it works perfectly fine, i'm an imbecile